# Unity loading TextAsset from Resources in Android fail

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm developing simple game with Unity 4.3.4.
my game app needs to load JSON text file in runtime. 
so I used like followings

```
TextAsset asset = Resources.Load ( "stages" ) as TextAsset;
string datafileContent = asset.text; 
doSomethingWithTextFile ( dataFileContent );
```

and I placed json text file in

```
\Assets\Resources\stages.json
```

It just works well! ... in Unity IDE only.
in Android, it fails to load test json file.

How can I this make possible?
please help.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

According to unity documentation [TextAsset](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/TextAsset.html) takes .txt files alone. so I would suggest you to convert the format to .txt and try it. This should work. I havent tried Json though but as far as I know it works on XML. and it should work in this case too.